Installing Chrome webdriver
I'm trying to configure my environment. I was told to download a driver for Chrome, which I did. I downloaded the file to my local Downloads folder, and the name of the file is chromedriver-win64.zip, with 3 files inside.
Then, I was told to run the 3 lines below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("/Users/danielgotlieb/Downloads/chromedriver"))

The first two were ok. I know I have to change the path inside "" on the 3rd line, but when I tried to use the location of the chrome file, I got an error saying "the path is not a valid file".
I tried
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("/Users/Dell/Downloads/chromedriver"))

I got:
Value error: the path is not a valid site.

I don't know what I did wrong. Is it the path? Is it the file name? I'm running the command within PyCharm.

If all else fails, try reading the documentation.

Starting from Selenium 4.6 you no longer need to explicitly download any drivers. Selenium uses the built-in "Selenium Manager" to do it for you.

Looking at the path and the driver you specified, it seems you are on Windows.
On Windows, absolute paths start with the drive. Usually, when you are in your user directory, it is the C: drive. Also, the Windows uses the backslashes (\) instead of the forward slashes (/) in paths
Additionally, the Chrome driver on Windows is an executable file, so you will need to include the .exe extension.
In your case, the correct path should look like this:
C:\Users\danielgotlieb\Downloads\chromedriver.exe
Since the backslash character is also the escape character in Python strings, you will need to double them ("\\").
The complete line should look like this:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:\\Users\\danielgotlieb\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"))


Those paths are likely on a Mac.

Yes, but the file name chromedriver-win64.zip is for the Windows driver.

The OP is obviously confused. :)
